Computation of "world-space face area divided by object-space face area"?
I am having difficulties understanding section 4.2 Seed processing in Umenhoffer et al - Hatching for Motion Picture Production 2011, specifically with respect to what the authors denote mesh distortion factor $\xi (x)$.
Here's the relevant (part of the) paragraph:


At a given frame, the local expansion or contraction between object-space and image-space at object-space point x is denoted
geometry factor G(x), which is in fact the Jacobi determinant of the mapping, and can be computed from the mesh distortion factor $\xi (x)$ [which?] is equal to the world-space face area divided by the object-space face area, the distance from the eye position e, the angle between the surface normal N(x) and the viewing direction, and the horizontal and vertical field-of-view angles $\phi (x)$ and $\phi (y)$.
$$ 
G(x)=\xi (x)\frac{(N(x)\centerdot(e-x))^+}{\mid e-x\mid^3}\frac{1}{4tan\frac{\phi_x}{2}tan\frac{\phi_y}{2}} 
$$


So most of this appears straight forward, but I am not sure I quite understand how they mean to compute $\xi (x)$
.
Would I evaluate the face area once after and once before transforming all vertices to world-space and then compute $\xi (x)=\frac{A_{world}}{A_{object}}$ ?
